# Eliminar punto marcador en ul y li

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, li

tengo un treeview con bootstrap, solamente que no logro eleiminar los puntos marcadores de cada ul y li
Como se ve en la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigué y todo me indica que debe capturarse con tipo:

```
list-style-type: none
```

Pero ya todo mi CSS tiene ese valor. Y aun asi no se elimina.
Dejo el HTML

```
<li class="item-5 deeper parent">
                        <a class="" href="#">
                            <span data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu-group-1" href="#sub-item-5" class="sign"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i></span>
                            <span class="lbl">Menu 2</span> 
                        </a>
                        <ul class="children nav-child unstyled  collapse" id="sub-item-5">
                            <li class="item-6">
                                <a class="" href="#">
                                    <span class="sign"><i class="icon-play"></i></span>
                                    <span class="lbl">Menu 2.1</span>                                    
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Si me puedan ayudar a eliminar esos puntos  gracias.

El boostrap que utilizo es la version 3

CSS

```
* T
------------------------- */
/* theme 1 */
#left ul.nav>li.item-1.parent>a {   /* BORDE*/
    border: solid 1px ;
}
#left ul.nav>li.item-1.parent>a>.sign,
#left ul.nav>li.item-1 li.parent>a>.sign{
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-color: ;
}
#left ul.nav>li.item-1 .lbl {  /*COLOR TEXTO BOTON*/
    color: ;
}
#left ul.nav>li.item-1 li.current>a .lbl {
    background-color: ;
    color: #fff!important;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, añade el código html y css relacionado con tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Sobre todo menciona que versión de Bootstrap estas incluyendo.

Comment: Lo habia añadido pero no se guardo al parecer

Comment: En qué parte de tu css estás agregando list-style-type: none? porque yo no lo veo

Comment: Lo esta tomando del CSS de boostrap directamente. O donde se debe colocar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo el código aquí con el style aplicado al vuelo, tú no lo estás poniendo en ningún lado por eso no te funciona

```
<!-- Aquí, style="list-style-type: none;" -->
    <li class="item-5 deeper parent" style="list-style-type: none;">
        <a class="" href="#">
            <span data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu-group-1" href="#sub-item-5" class="sign"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i></span>
            <span class="lbl">Menu 2</span> 
        </a>
        <ul class="children nav-child unstyled  collapse" id="sub-item-5">
            <!-- Y aquí de nuevo, y siempre que quieras hacer un <li> sin estilo deberías ponerlo... y no lo haces en ninguna parte -->
            <li class="item-6" style="list-style-type: none;">
                <a class="" href="#">
                    <span class="sign"><i class="icon-play"></i></span>
                    <span class="lbl">Menu 2.1</span>                                    
                </a>
            </li>
        
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Tecnicamente si, pero necesitarás también ponerle `display: list-item;` Pero... `list-style-type:none` hace que el elemento no tenga "bullets" o puntitos de lista. Un div ya no los tiene por defecto. Si quieres ponérselo a un div para que todos sus `li` tengan esa característica, no funcionará... tendrás que ponerlo manualmente en los `li` o usar una función que lo haga por tí